# Haskell how to determine if an expression is simple or not?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am writing a function to determine if an expression is simple or not. A simple expression, in my case, is an expression that does not have an available function call. I have the following Exp types:

```
data Exp = IntExp Integer
         | VarExp String
         | LamExp String Exp
         | IfExp Exp Exp Exp
         | OpExp String Exp Exp
         | AppExp Exp Exp
         deriving (Eq)
```

I do believe the type signature for my function will be of the following:

```
isSimple :: Exp -> Bool
```

Here are some test cases:

```
Main Lib> isSimple (AppExp (VarExp "f") (IntExp 10))
False
*Main Lib> isSimple (OpExp "+" (IntExp 10) (VarExp "v"))
True
*Main Lib> isSimple (OpExp "+" (IntExp 10) (AppExp (VarExp "f") (VarExp "v")))
False
```

As you see, first and third expressions have application expressions to functions and therefore not simple. But I do not even know how to start to function in order to decide. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.
Edit:
Sorry, I should've added my current progress. I have a straightforward approach, which actually seemed too simple:

```
isSimple (AppExp e1 e2) = False
isSimple (IntExp e1) = True
isSimple (VarExp s1) = True

isSimple (IfExp e1 e2 e3) = (isSimple e1) && (isSimple e2) && (isSimple e3)
isSimple (OpExp s1 e1 e2) = (isSimple e1) && (isSimple e2)
```

But also lambda expressions would be a bit more tricky.

Comment: Proceed by recursion on your `Exp` type. Using pattern matching, handle each constructor.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: Added my progress, but seems overly simple.

Comment: Your attempt looks OK to me. I'm unsure about how you want to handle the lambda expressions. Can you provide some examples using lambdas so that we can understand the result you intend to obtain? Ideally, provide a lambda where we should return true, and another one for false.

Comment: It is not really clear when you consider an expression to be simple for a lambda expression. Can you explain *what* you want the function to do?

Comment: I would suggest a lambda expression is simple if (and only if) its body is simple.

Comment: Thank you, everyone, for the great, I thought of a similar approach with @chepner that I can think of lambda expressions as if they are operator expressions. Thanks again for your help! Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR A lambda expression is simple if (and only if) its body is simple.

---

A lambda expression is, in some sense, just a special case of an operator expression, except the semantics of the operation are encoded in the grammar. You could imagine, for example, splitting `OpExp` into multiple operator-specific cases:

```
data Exp = IntExp Integer
     | VarExp String
     | LamExp String Exp
     | IfExp Exp Exp Exp
     | AddExp Exp Exp  -- x + y
     | MulExp Exp Exp  -- x * y
     | AndExpr Exp Exp -- x && y
     | ...
     | AppExp Exp Exp
```

But we don't have separate rules for every operator; we just have one which stores the operator in question as data.

You can take this idea further by treating a lambda expression as just another kind of operator expression.

```
data Exp = IntExp Integer
     | VarExp String
     | IfExp Exp Exp Exp
     | OpExp Exp Exp
     | AppExp Exp Exp
```

where a lambda expression like `λx . x + 3` becomes

```
OpExp "λ" (VarExp "x") (OpExp "+" (VarExp "x") (IntExp 3))
```

(Just like both arguments for `+` or `*` have to be `IntExp`s or expressions that evaluate to `IntExp`s, `λ` requires its first argument to be a `VarExp`. These are semantic constraints that just aren't captured by the grammar itself.)

In this case, the definition of `isSimple` for `OpExp` still holds: the expression is simple as long as the bound variable (the first argument) and the body (the second argument) are both simple.

As such, it seems perfectly reasonable to define

```
isSimple (LamExp _ e) = isSimple e
```

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation. I was thinking about a similar approach myself and came to edit my question with a comment just to see your perfect explanation.